# Get jQuery Data and use it as a MAX value of a number field in laravel

Tags: jquery, laravel

Hi I have this jQuery script that grabs a certain laravel variable and set as the max value of a number field. so that I can make sure that the user can't input greater than the value of the variable. Here's the script

```
var $limitQty = $('#product_name_1').val();
$('#product_name_1'+$orderItem_id).on('mouseup keyup', function () {
    $(this).val(Math.min({{$remainingDeliveries}}, Math.max(0, $(this).val())));
});
```

here's the number field

```
<input class="form-control qty_in" type='text' data-type="qty_in" id='qty_in_1' name='qty_in[]' data-max='{{$remainingDeliveries}}' onkeyup='check(this);' for="1"/>
```

they works fine

Now my problem is I have form, but same number field, that need this script which has different data source. The data is came dynamically from autocomplete jQuery script. here's the code,

```
//autocomplete script
$(document).on('focus','.autocomplete_txt',function(){
  type = $(this).data('type');

  if(type =='product_code' )autoType='product_code'; 
  if(type =='product_name' )autoType='name'; 
  // if(type =='qty_in' )autoType='qty_in'; 
  // if(type =='product_id' )autoType='id'; 

   $(this).autocomplete({
       minLength: 0,
       source: function( request, response ) {
            $.ajax({
                url: "{{ route('searchStock') }}",
                dataType: "json",
                data: {
                    term : request.term,
                    type : type,
                },
                success: function(data) {
                    var array = $.map(data, function (item) {
                       return {
                           label: item[autoType],
                           value: item[autoType],
                           data : item
                       }
                   });
                    response(array)
                }
            });
       },
       select: function( event, ui ) {
           var data = ui.item.data;           
           id_arr = $(this).attr('id');
           id = id_arr.split("_");
           elementId = id[id.length-1];
           $('#product_code_'+elementId).val(data.product_code);
           $('#product_name_'+elementId).val(data.name);
           $('#qty_in_'+elementId).val(data.qty_in);
           $('#qty_out_'+elementId).val(data.qty_out);
           $('#product_id_'+elementId).val(data.id);
       }
   });
});
```

What I am trying to accomplish is, if possible, I want to get the value from  $('#qty_in_'+elementId).val(data.qty_in); and put it in `$(this).val(Math.min({{--- PUT HERE ---}}, Math.max(0, $(this).val())));` is it possible? Help me please. Thank you so much in advance!

Comment: What is the id of your $(this).val()

Answer (score 0):

You can add data attribute in your input and access it to your own needs

```
select: function( event, ui ) {
       ...
       $('#qty_in_'+elementId).val(data.qty_in).data('max',data.qty_in);
}
```

Comment: Hi @Paul this is still not preventing the use to enter greater than the max value. is it possible to incorporate the result from $('#qty_out_'+elementId).val(data.qty_out).data('max',data.qty_out); to this script   $('#qty_out_1').on('mouseup keyup', function () {
                          $(this).val(Math.min(500, Math.max(1, $(this).val())));  ?

Answer (score 0):

This one works for me.

select: function( event, ui ) {
       ...
       $('#qty_in_'+elementId).val(data.qty_in).prop('max',data.qty_in);
}